# How can I change one specific character in a 2D character array (at a position input by user) using pointers (C)?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I'm trying to create a C program that would print a 3x3 grid of underscores with one of the underscores replaced with an 'X' at the row and column number input by the user. My code is able to take the user inputs and print out the grid of underscores, but it only replaces an underscore with an 'X' sometimes and it usually isn't in the place I want it. Does anyone know what the issue is or how I can fix it? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char  *boardptr[3][3] = {"_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"};
 
    int i;
    int j;
    
    int playrow;
    int playcol;
    
    printf("Please enter a row number: ");
    scanf("%d", &playrow);
    
    printf("Please enter a column number: ");
    scanf("%d", &playcol);
    
    boardptr[playrow][playcol] = "X";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%s ", boardptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce. *What* did you enter? Entering `1 2` replaces the last element on the second row.

Comment: This code works (for me) for row and column values 0 thru 2. Maybe you forgot that array indexes begin at 0 and end at n-1?

Comment: Be aware that it is very unusual to make a 2D array of `char *` like this. It makes much more sense to make it a 2D array of `char` and to assign `'_'` or `'X'`. You are currently basically wasting half of the memory due to the strings needing to be NUL-terminated.

Comment: @Cheatah: the '\0' "only" double the number of bytes needed. And in fact, not really. The storage of a pointer for each of the 9 cases if far worse (typically ×4 or ×8, depending on the architecture). A ``char [3][3]`` using 9 bytes, when a ``char *[3][3]``  would use 72 bytes for all the ``char **``. That is the waste. The pointed ``char *``, ``"X"`` or ``"_"`` indeed use 2 byes each (1 for the char, another for the terminal ``'\0'``). But since they are constant string, they are mutualized. So, as long as they are all either ``"X"`` or ``"_"``, the content is only 4 bytes for the whole array